# Sticky=W by default for all objects (Tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to have `sticky=W` **by default** for grid positionning in tkinter ?

```
Label(master, text="First").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Second").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
...
```

This would prevent from setting `sticky=W` 20 times ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to do this. You could create your own helper function, or you could subclass every widget, or you could redefine the core grid command via monkeypatching, but why? All it does is save you a couple keystrokes, and it makes your code harder to understand by others, since your default isn't *the* default.

Comment: Disagree. If it is a consistent default application-wize, it is error prone to have to type those `sticky=W` each time. Any documented solution may do, including monkey patching and subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a job for a helper function:

```
def grid(widget, sticky=W, **kwargs):
    widget.grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)

grid(Label(master, text="First"), row=0)
...
```

You probably could do some hackery and replace `tkinter.Widget.grid` with a wrapper around `tkinter.Widget.grid` ;-).  But that's more complicated and limiting than this solution IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it possible to define a "global"  `sticky` value for all objects of a tkinter `Frame` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass Label:

```
class LabelW(Label):
    def grid(self, **options):
        options['sticky'] = options.get('sticky') or 'W'
        super(LabelW, self).grid(**options)

LabelW(master, text="First").grid(row=0)
```

Comment: I thought about this, but it seems like it would quickly become annoying if you have to grid 7 or 8 different widget types.

Comment: @mgilson you can subclass Widget and monkey patch tkinter, or subclass all the widgets with new base class, but no standard way that I know.

Comment: you don't need to subclass `Widget` in order to monkey patch it ;-).  But, FWIW, this is why I suggested a helper function.

Comment: @mgilson I already upvoted that :) I added subclassing aproach as a mean to achieve desired functionality without need to change already written code, i.e. name it `Label(tkinter.Label)` for example.